# Barra de carregamento com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, ajax

Algumas vezes vejo barras de carregamento com percentagem em sites que creio eu, sobrescrevem o comportamento padrão da página ao carregar (tela branca até que o conteúdo esteja pronto). Existem alguns plugins jQuery que fazem isso, mas quero entender exatamente como funciona esse processo com JS puro.

Eu me baseio em quê pra descobrir o percentual de carregamento em uma página?

Comment: neste caso, a requisição para o servidor é um download de dados? ou alguma rotina intensiva?

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Se você acessar essa página, vai ver que de alguma forma o plugin jQuery detecta o progresso de carregamento da página e o representa graficamente. É isso que quero saber como funciona....

Comment: é possivel fazer com `XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function, false)`, porém a pagina precisa expor o seu trabanho no Header atraves da propriedade `Content-Length`.

Comment: Interessante o que disse @TobyMosque. Vou ler mais à respeito...

Answer (score 2):

Usando como base o plugin pace.js (https://github.com/HubSpot/pace), ele utiliza diversos métodos para detectar o percentual de carregamento da página:

  Requisições Ajax:
    **-**
    O plugin verifica as requisições, calculando o percentual de cada uma dependendo do seu tipo:
      Se a requisição for um XMLHttpRequest ele utiliza o evento "progress", que retorna um objeto com o tamanho do arquivo sendo baixado e quanto ja foi concluído, se estiver disponível o Content-Length no Header da requisição de resposta. Além de também verificar os eventos "load", "abort", "timeout" e "error" para determinar se a requisição terminou.

```
request.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
      //Verifica se Content-Length foi declarado no Header de resposta
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        //Calcula a porcentagem de acordo com o quanto já foi baixado.
        return _this.progress = 100 * evt.loaded / evt.total;
      } else {
        //Se não há Content-Length retorna uma porcentagem sintética.
        return _this.progress = _this.progress + (100 - _this.progress) / 2;
      }
    }, false);
```

  Se o tipo de requisição for um WebSocket ele verifica os eventos "error" e "open" para determinar se a requisição terminou.

```
SocketRequestTracker = (function() {
  function SocketRequestTracker(request) {
    var event, _j, _len1, _ref2,
      _this = this;
    this.progress = 0;
    _ref2 = ['error', 'open'];
    //Registra listener aos eventos acima para determinar quando conexão estiver estabelecida, ou não.
    for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref2.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
      event = _ref2[_j];
      request.addEventListener(event, function() {
        return _this.progress = 100;
      }, false);
    }
  }

  return SocketRequestTracker;
})();
```

  Documento HTML:
    **-**
    O plugin utiliza o
    *document.readystate*
    para determinar o estado no qual o documento está ("loading", "interactive", "complete") e atribui uma porcentagem para cada.

```
DocumentMonitor = (function() {
  //Determina porcentagens para cada estado de document.readyState.
  DocumentMonitor.prototype.states = {
    loading: 0,
    interactive: 50,
    complete: 100
  };

  function DocumentMonitor() {
    var _onreadystatechange, _ref2,
      _this = this;
    //Verifica document.readystate e atribui valor ao estado atual da página
    this.progress = (_ref2 = this.states[document.readyState]) != null ? _ref2 : 100;
    _onreadystatechange = document.onreadystatechange;
    //Nas mudanças de estado atualiza o valor da porcentagem
    document.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (_this.states[document.readyState] != null) {
        _this.progress = _this.states[document.readyState];
      }
      return typeof _onreadystatechange === "function" ? _onreadystatechange.apply(null, arguments) : void 0;
    };
  }

  return DocumentMonitor;
})();
```

  Lag no Loop de Eventos:
    **-**
    O plugin verifica, através do lag no loop de eventos, se existe código javascript sendo executado e calcula um porcentagem relativa ao lag.

```
EventLagMonitor = (function() {
  function EventLagMonitor() {
    var avg, interval, last, points, samples,
      _this = this;
    this.progress = 0;
    avg = 0;
    samples = [];
    points = 0;
    last = now();
    //Utiliza um timer para calcular o Lag no loop de eventos do javascript
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var diff;
      //Calcula a diferença entre o tempo de execução determinado para o Timer (50ms) e o tempo real de execução
      diff = now() - last - 50;
      last = now();
      samples.push(diff);
      if (samples.length > options.eventLag.sampleCount) {
        samples.shift();
      }
      //Calcula a amplitude media a partir dos Lag's salvos
      avg = avgAmplitude(samples);
      //Verifica se a amplitude dos Lag's está acima do limite na execução do javascript
      if (++points >= options.eventLag.minSamples && avg < options.eventLag.lagThreshold) {
        _this.progress = 100;
        return clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        //Se estiver, calcula a porcentagem a partir dessa amplitude.
        return _this.progress = 100 * (3 / (avg + 3));
      }
    }, 50);
  }

  return EventLagMonitor;
})();
```

  Elementos HTML(opcional):
    **-**
    O plugin verifica a existência de certos elementos predeterminados usando o
    *document.querySelector*
    .

```
//De acordo com a documentação - Define as classes/id's a serem verificados pelo pace.js
paceOptions = {
 elements: {
  selectors: ['.timeline,.timeline-error', '.user-profile,.profile-error']
 }
}
```

```
//Para verificar a existência dos elementos no documento
ElementTracker = (function() {
  function ElementTracker(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    this.progress = 0;
    this.check();
  }

  ElementTracker.prototype.check = function() {
    var _this = this;
    if (document.querySelector(this.selector)) {
      return this.done();
    } else {
      return setTimeout((function() {
        return _this.check();
      }), options.elements.checkInterval);
    }
  };

  ElementTracker.prototype.done = function() {
    return this.progress = 100;
  };

  return ElementTracker;
})();
```